# nodejs async.whilst will only invoke once

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

As the question states, async.whilst will only invoke once. However, if I pass an array containing 2 objects (length of 2), it will only invoke once -- instead of once for each index of the array.

```
//if previous awsKeys detected in req.body / images are detected : delete them.
    exports.multipleDelete = function (req, res, next) {
        var body = req.body;
      //if object already has existing keys, they will be in the body.existingKeys array.
        var awsKeyTrash = body.existingKeys;
        if (awsKeyTrash !== undefined) {
            var j = 0;
            async.whilst(
                function () {
                    return j < awsKeyTrash.length;
                },
                function () {
                    var picInfo = awsKeyTrash[j];
                    s3.deleteObject({
                        Bucket: aws.bucket,
                        Key: picInfo.key
                    }, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('delete err', err);
                    //if there is an error, set pic information to original
                            req.body[picInfo.name] = picInfo.picUrl;
                            req.body[picInfo.key] = picInfo.awsKeyVal;
                            j++;
                        };
                        console.log('deleted')
                        console.log('j ', j)
                        j++;
                        res.send('deleted');
                    });
                },
                function (err) {
            console.log('profile edit , pic delteion err : ', err);
            return res.status(409).send({
              message: ['Unable to edit profile at this time. Try again']
            });
                })
            next();
        }
        else {
            next();
        }
    }
```

here is an example of of the body.existingKeys array:

```
     Array[
        {
        awsKeyVal: "users/66085aa8-6501-4f90-973c-1b18edf4087eScreenShot2016-12-05at10.03.07PM.png",
        key: "awsPictureKey",
        name: "picture",
        picUrl: "https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/users/66085aa8-6501-4f90-973c-1b18edf4087eScreenShot2016-12-05at10.03.07PM.png"
    }, 
        {
        awsKeyVal: "coverphoto/7180d1ae-748c-4b96-86cb-5cb29cebdc9bScreenShot2016-12-10at3.13.18PM.png",
        key: "awsCoverKey",
        name: "cover",
        picUrl: "https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/coverphoto/7180d1ae-748c-4b96-86cb-5cb29cebdc9bScreenShot2016-12-10at3.13.18PM.png"
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[async.whylist](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#whilst) takes a callback that you aren't calling.

It looks like your `next()` is misplaced as well.

Additionally, the last function is not an error handler. It just takes the error as the first argument, which may be null if there is no error.

```
async.whilst(
    function () {
        return j < awsKeyTrash.length;
    },
    function ( callback ) {
        var picInfo = awsKeyTrash[j];
        s3.deleteObject({
            Bucket: aws.bucket,
            Key: picInfo.key
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('delete err', err);
                //if there is an error, set pic information to original
                req.body[picInfo.name] = picInfo.picUrl;
                req.body[picInfo.key] = picInfo.awsKeyVal;
                j++;
            };
            console.log('deleted')
            console.log('j ', j)
            j++;
            res.send('deleted');

            callback();
        });
    },
    function (err) {

        if( err ) {
            console.log('profile edit , pic delteion err : ', err);
            return res.status(409).send({
                message: ['Unable to edit profile at this time. Try again']
            });
        }

        // If someone else handles errors, pass it on here. Otherwise,
        // throw or something else to block program flow
        next(err);
    }
);
```

Comment: Makes sense. About your error handling comment, wouldn't the return within the if (err) conditional block the program flow? I can make that another question if you'd like to get credit, since it is a separate issue. thanks again.

Comment: It depends. It's inside an async function so it will just return the result of res.send to the parent handler, whatever that is. Probably not what you want.